# That game of a human and an alien telling stories in a doomed space ship

Tags: product-identification

I believe that at least two years ago (and my memory is consequently hazy), when I had no people to play strange games with and was not that interested in … anthropological games yet, I encountered a game matching the following points. So far trying to look through past Game Chef and Epimas lists (those are the two main places I imagined I might have seen it) and general searching have not led me back to it.

### Description

The game is a two-player storytelling game set on a doomed space ship, on which only the human captain and a distinctly non-human alien are present. The game is about these two sharing their cultural heritage and what it means to be human/that particular type of non-human in the form of stories. It will end with some foreseeable catastrophic event, so it might even be a timed game or a poem. In my mental image (which is not trustworthy), the game is a conversation structure and does not contain a randomized resolution or generation mechanic.

#### Influences/Points of Confusion

There is a definite Darmok-vibe to the game. I believe, but don't know because I didn't know Darmok when I encountered the game and may therefore have mixed up things, that the episode is mentioned in the game's list of inspirations.

[Last Transmission](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v97X32s9wbxBhOLWqH6-gKe6WcUuy7VwnyiJULoKhTM/edit?usp=sharing) is a candidate I rejected recently, because while I might misremember several things, I believe I would have remembered a GM using Google Translate – some of the other mismatches I would accept as tricks of my faulty memory, but in concert they also tell me it's not The game.

ЭПОС ХИЩНИКА may be either an influence on the game or something I confuse it with, because I discussed this game with someone and they mentioned this short story. There may be more elements of Леонид Каганов's short story in my description than in the original game I encountered due to this.

Comment: Any other details you can remember? Mechanics or rules? Type of doom? Ending?

Comment: Not really, and now that I have looked for it for quite some time finding other stuff, there's also a high chance that whatever I “remember” is due to interference from other sources.

Comment: While I haven't heard of such a game, that's almost exactly the plot of the movie Enemy Mine. Perhaps that might help?

Comment: This game sounds familiar. I haven't played it, but i think it is a game in its own right, not just an amalgam of other cultural bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the game you are looking for is [Our Radios are Dying](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/259852/Our-Radios-Are-Dying) by [Aura Belle](http://caitlynnbelle.com) or a rules hack thereof. Though this game has a much greater focus on the emotional history of the characters than what you describe it is the closest match I know of.

Comment: Huh. I think I'd remember if a strongly emotional romantic forbidden relationship was a core part of the game, but there are indeed a few things in the game and the language used to convey it that feel familiar. Have a +1 for now.

Comment: Dang, I thought I had it! Well I guess you could hack Our Radios Are Dying into something close to the game you remember? I'd definitely play it.

Comment: It may be you have it and my memory has been strangely overloaded by encountering other things. I'll have to mull over it some more.